# Extending Vuetify Component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

What is the best way to extend vue (vuetify) component `v-select`.

For example, I want to create `<v-city></v-city>` component that extends `v-select` with minimal `props`, async items loaded and one of items selected.

I've started with `template`

```
<template>
    <v-select
        :items="items"
        v-model="item"
        required
        return-object
        autocomplete
        item-text="name"
        item-value="id"
    ></v-select>
</template>
```

and `script`

```
<script>
    export default {
        name: 'v-city',
        data()
        {
            return {
                item: null,
                items: [],
                disabled: true
            };
        },
        created()
        {
            this.$http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: '/api.cities'
            })
                .then(response => this.items = response.data)
                .catch(console.warn);
        },
        methods: {},
        watch: {
            item(nv)
            {
                this.$emit('update', nv.id);
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

And usage:
`<v-city @update="local.city = arguments[0]"></v-city>`

What I want to archive  is:
`<v-city v-model="local.city" label="Select city"></v-city>`

Answer (score 8):

The best way to "extend" any component is to wrap it.

```html
<template>
  <v-select v-bind="$attrs" v-on="$listeners">
    <!-- pass through scoped slots -->
    <template v-for="(_, name) in $scopedSlots" v-slot:[name]="data">
      <slot :name="name" v-bind="data" />
    </template>

    <!-- pass through normal slots -->
    <template v-for="(_, name) in $slots" v-slot:[name]>
      <slot :name="name" />
    </template>
  </v-select>
</template>
```

Prop defaults can just be added inline:

```html
<v-select open-on-clear v-bind="$attrs" v-on="$listeners">
```

Some components (for example v-checkbox) also use a non-default prop and event for the model, so you may also need to set that for `v-model` to work properly:

```html
<script>
  export default {
    model: {
      // These are the default values
      prop: 'value',
      event: 'input'
    }
  }
</script>
```

---

You might find some other answers that say to use `extends` as well:

```html
<script>
  import { VSelect } from 'vuetify/lib'
  export default {
    extends: VSelect,
  }
</script>
```

This *can* work sometimes, for example if you just want to override one of the component's methods. Do not combine `extends` with `<template>` though, that will override the render function and almost always break the component.

---

v3 is similar but $listeners and $scopedSlots no longer exist, and v-model is always `modelValue`:

```html
<template>
  <v-select v-bind="$attrs">
    <template v-for="(_, name) in $slots" v-slot:[name]="data">
      <slot :name="name" v-bind="data" />
    </template>
  </v-select>
</template>
```

Comment: Worked for me! This should be accepted as the answer.

Comment: `$scopedSlots` are removed in Vue.3 see [docs](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/migration/slots-unification.html#overview)
But my scopedSlots aren't available, anyway. 
I fixed this by: `<template v-for="(_, scopedSlotName) in $scopedSlots" v-slot:[scopedSlotName]="data">
      <slot :scopedSlotName="name" v-bind="data" />
    </template>`

Comment: Can you add some notes about render it with $props/$listeners in this [official example](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/frequently-asked-questions/#questions)? It can help other peoples.

Answer (score 4):

To answer on my own question: use `v-bind="this.$attrs"` to get all "parent" attributes applied on child component. Also use `this.$listeners.input` to change value. Probably not ideal and only solution, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can just wrap v-select component wth your v-city and pass props via v-city component. Than you can define component globally if needed