# Set props globally for a Vuetify component (`v-data-table` in my case)

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

My use case is as follows:

The default value of the prop `rows-per-page-items` for `v-data-table` is 
`[5,10,25,{"text":"$vuetify.dataIterator.rowsPerPageAll","value":-1}]` [API doc](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables#api)

I want to ovveride this prop and have the new values as `[10,25,50]`. Now the data-table component is being used at many places in my app. So, my question is:

Is there a way to override this prop globally so that it is changed for all the tables in my app?

Comment: I might be wrong but I don't think there is currently a way of doing it. Best you can do is have your own global variable and assign it to each of your grids. You can probably log a ticket on their github page. It is quite trivial but I can see the use in it.

Comment: I would do this by extending the v-data-table component. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48310902/extending-vuetify-component).